# How to remove Array duplicates in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array of HTMLElements. I want to remove the duplicates

```
const element = event.target as HTMLElement;

if (element.classList.contains('singleRowPath')) {
  const gEle = element.closest('g');

  for (let i = 0; i <= this.selectedRowFromMultiSeats.length; i++) {
    if (this.selectedRowFromMultiSeats[i] !== gEle) {
      this.selectedRowFromMultiSeats.push(gEle);
    }
  }

console.error(this.selectedRowFromMultiSeats);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard way using filter,

```
let uniqueElements = selectedRowFromMultiSeats.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
```

Using set,

```
let uniqueElements = [...new Set(selectedRowFromMultiSeats)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uses Set,which will be much convenient approach and will give you unique elements in an array 
let uniqueElements = [...new Set(selectedRowFromMultiSeats)];